# Move individual axes

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

In matplotlib, I would like to move the two rightmost axes without screwing up everything else in the figure. I think I could do that with `GridSpec`, is there a way to do it with normal subplots?

Take as example these subplots:

`fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, 3, figsize=(8 * 2.5, 5 * 2.5), sharex=True, sharey=True, constrained_layout=False)`

[image]

I would like to obtain something like (done with MSpaint):
[image]
Thanks!

Comment: You can reposition any axes by using the `Axes` method: `Axes.set_position()`. This takes as an argument a list of instructions about the axes positioning in the figure. This list looks like this: [initial position x, initial position y , width, height], where all components go from 0 to 1 and the initial positions refer to the bottom left corner of the axes. You can use this method on the two axes you want to put to the side.

Comment: ok, but if I want to change relative to the initial width and height, how do I get width and height?

Comment: got it. Axes.get_position() will return a box that containx x0, y0, x1, y1 (initial positions and final positions). x1-x0 is the width.